# DT_DBTIMESTAMP2 having only 3 digits

Tags: sql-server, ssis, rownum

I'm having `(DT_DBTIMESTAMP2,7)GETDATE()` in SSIS Derived Column Transformation and Table column with datetime2(7).
Even though I set 7 Digit Second Scale in both, but seems it comes only 3 digit.
For example, I expected like **'2018-05-02 16:45:15.6192346'** but it comes **'2018-05-02 16:45:15.6190000**'.

The reason why I need the millseconds, I'd like to sort out the latest record from any duplications using timestamp. I realized only 3 digit second scale is not enough for this pourpose.

Except for Derived Column Transformation and Table Columns, is there any requrired setting in SSIS package?  Any advices would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`GETDATE()` returns a `datetime`, you should use `SYSDATETIME()` instead. See [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/getdate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

**edit**

As noted by Larnu, you are probably using SSIS expression [GETDATE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/getdate-ssis-expression?view=sql-server-2017), rather that the sql expression GETDATE as I assumed. The point is more-or-less the same though. GETDATE returns a `DT_DBTIMESTAMP`, where "The fractional seconds have a maximum scale of 3 digits." ([Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/integration-services-data-types?view=sql-server-2017)).

Comment: I think the OP is using the SSIS expression  [`GETDATE()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/getdate-ssis-expression?view=sql-server-2017), not the SQL Server expression [`GETDATE()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/getdate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). `(DT_DBTIMESTAMP2,7)GETDATE()` would not be valid SQL Server syntax.

Comment: @Larnu, Good point, I wasn't aware there was a similarly named SSIS expression. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

Although this is almost the same as what HoneyBadger has said, I'm expanding a little, as the OP isn't using the `GETDATE()` expression in SQL Server. The value `2018-05-02 16:45:15.619` could never be returned by `GETDATE()` (Transact-SQL) as it's only accurate to 1/300th of a second (thus the final digit can only every be 0,3, and 7 (technically 0, 333333333~ and 666666666~, which is why the final digit is a 7, as it's rounded up)).

In SSIS the [`GETDATE()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/getdate-ssis-expression?view=sql-server-2017) expression returns a datatype of `DB_TIMESTAMP`. According to the [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/integration-services-data-types?view=sql-server-2017):

> A timestamp structure that consists of year, month, day, hour, minute,
>   second, and fractional seconds. The fractional seconds have a maximum
>   scale of 3 digits.

Thus, the last 4 characters are lost. Unfortunately, I don't believe there is a function in SSIS that returns the the current date and time to the accuracy you require. Thus, if you need this high level, you'll likely need to use an expression in SQL Server that does, such as [`SYSDATETIME()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sysdatetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) that HoneyBadger recommended.

Comment: Lamu and HoneyBadger, many thanks for your prompt and kind reply. Thanks to you, finally understand why it came with 3 digits. Unfortunately, SSIS seems not support sysdatetime(), so I'll try other solutions for my purpose (and maybe comes back if I would encounter other issue...). Thanks a lot !

Comment: @Sachiko, the SSIS GETDATE() returns DB_DBTIMESTAMP rather than DB_DBTIMESTAMP2 so it's only 3 decimals. If you need higher precision, you could use a Script transformation to assign DateTime.Now to a DB_DBTIMESTAMP2 column.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your precious advice, @Dan :) I’ll try to get the higher precision by any scripts.